# Referencing material from an .edu worksheet

Tags: citations

A [worksheet from lmu.edu](https://academics.lmu.edu/media/lmuacademics/cures/urbanecolab/module04/M4_L4.1_S_Key_Final.pdf) claims the LD50 of particular substances, are these numbers citeable?

I want to be able to say, "The LD50 of *whatever* is *whatever* because this worksheet from a website that ends in .edu said so," without looking silly.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t do it. You will look not only silly but also wildly irresponsible, considering that you are talking about, literally, **lethal doses of chemical substances**. What if this authorless document contains a typo? What if your own document helps propagate false and dangerous information that will end up being cited by others and eventually used by someone? Do you see how this might be, um, just a little bit problematic?

My advice is, find an *authoritative* source on this topic and cite it instead. In addition, you should know that google isn’t the only research tool in existence, and web pages and publicly posted PDF documents aren’t the only type of information source, or the most reliable one ([slightly relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1301/)). For scientific and scholarly purposes, there are much higher quality information sources, and well-known methods for finding them. Your local library is a good resource to get started if you need help, or you can post a question on the relevant topical stack exchange (e.g., chemistry.stackexchange in the current case) where I’m sure someone will be able to suggest something useful.

Comment: [Another relevant XKCD.](https://xkcd.com/978/)

Comment: There's probably some authoritative toxicology handbook or database for this kind of information.

Comment: @henning - there are several sources which a local ES&H professional has on their bookshelf (or knows online). Although, of course, the LD50 of all substances has not been measured. The first place to look would be at an SDS or two on the chemical.